# SLIM ERROR TYPE: Slim\Exception\ContainerValueNotFoundException

Tags: php, twig, slim-3

I'm pretty new to using slim framework with twig-view. I am seeing this error when I try to render view from slim container, this is the code that returns an error page.

```
<?php

$app->get('/home', function($request, $response){
return $this->$view->render($response, 'home.twig');    
}); 

?>
```

The above code returns this error[Slim application error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Enb1.png), but when I return a simple string like the example below:

```
<?php

$app->get('/home', function($request, $response){
return "Hello World!";  
}); 

?>
```

It outputs  Hello World! correctly on the browser, but when I try this:

```
<?php

$app->get('/home', function($request, $response){
return $this->$view->render($response, 'home.twig');    
}); 

?>
```

It returns the error [Slim application error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hutc.png). The below code is my index page.

```
<?php
session_start();
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App([
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,
    ]
]);

$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['view'] = function($container){
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig(__DIR__ . '/../resources/views/home.twig', [
        'cache' => false,
    ]); 

    $view->addExtension(new Slim/Views/TwigExtension(

    $container->router,
    $container->request->getUri()
));

return $view;
};



require __DIR__ . '/../app/route.php';

?>
```

On

What am I not doing correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to access `$this->$view` but the container only knows about `$this->view`.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your views folder, not your file.

```
$container['view'] = function ($container) {

  $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig(__DIR__ . '/../resources/views', [
    'cache' => false
  ]);

  $view->addExtension(new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(
    $container->router,
    $container->request->getUri()
  ));

  return $view;
}
```

And in your `route` you can do this

```
$app->get('/', function ($request, $response) {
  return $this->container->view->render($response, 'home.twig');
});
```

Notice that home.twig must be inside views folder.

Comment: My home.twig is located in my root folder resources/views/home.twig, I wonder why I'm having Twig_Error_Loader type error.

Comment: Like I said, in `$container['view']` you should define your folder not your file

Comment: not this `$view = new \Slim\Views\Twig(__DIR__ . '/../resources/views/home.twig', [
        'cache' => false,
    ]);`

but this `$view = new \Slim\Views\Twig(__DIR__ . '/../resources/views', [
    'cache' => false
  ]);`

Comment: I have corrected that already, this is how my code looks'<?php

$app->get('/', function($request, $response){
  return $this->view->render($response, 'home.twig'); 
}); 

?>
'

Comment: `$this->container->view` because view registered inside `$container`

Comment: Hello Gabriel, like you rightly commented, please in my ''$container['view']'

Comment: Hello Gabriel, like you rightly commented, I need to define my folder and not file, do you mean:
'$container['view'] = function($container){
 $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig(__DIR__ . '/../resources/views', [
  'cache' => false,
 ]);' and not this:
'$container['view'] = function($container){
 $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig(__DIR__ . '/../resources/views/home.twig', [
  'cache' => false,
 ]);'?

Comment: This my route; please confirm that this code is ok.
'<?php

$app->get('/home', function($request, $response){
  return $this->container->view->render($response, 'home.twig'); 
}); 

?>
'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your .htaccess file exits in the root folder with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```